# Shifting character in list of list 1 position left or right. After shifting return true if it was possible and false if it wasn't

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, character, shift

A random character is instructed to move 1 position left or right if this is possible and return True and if it isn't possible then return False.

Example:

```
#Input:

[['.', 'B', 'B', '.', '.', '.']]

move_sideways("B", "RIGHT", lot0)

#Output:

True
[['.', '.', 'B', 'B', '.', '.']]
```

So it was possible for both B's to move to the right one position. If one of the B's was in the first position and was instructed to move left it would return False because this would be impossible. Same if the B was in the last position and instructed to move right.

This is my code so far but I really can't figure out how to accomplish this. Maybe I would use pop

```
def move_sideways(symbol, direction, lst):

    for symbol in range(len(lst))
        lst[1:] + lst[:1]
            return lst
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I apologize I did actually include input and output but I literally have no idea how to write this code unlike the other questions I've posted recently. I'm not necessarily looking for the answer though it would be useful I would also appreciate advice or even steps on how this could be done

Comment: @n00bprogrammer22 this is not a personal tutorial website

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Lets say you had list ['A','B','C'] and you asked move_sideways("B", "RIGHT", lot0). What would the list look like after ? would it be ['A','.','B','C'] or maybe ['A','C','B'] or ['C','A','B'] ?

Comment: @Whud I believe after being told to move right it would look like ['A','C','B']

Comment: @Whud do you have any advice on how this could be done? I was thinking maybe using the pop function but don't know how I would set it up.

Comment: I saw this example few times in last two days - I believe you can find it on SO.

Comment: @furas I can't find any other posts on SO I just edited my code above with how I think this could be done but I don't know how I would only have that happen when the character that is inputted is in the list

Comment: `if "B" in ['.', 'B', 'B', '.', '.', '.']:`

Comment: Also as comment on your requirement;   In general the pythonic way is to not return Anything  on in-place operations and  instead of returning false if unsuccessful, raise an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient way to do it but it works. I'm happy to answer any questions about it but I'm going to bed soon.

```
def move_sideways(symbol, direction, lst):

    if symbol not in lst:
        print('symbol is not in list')
        return False

    ind = [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x == symbol] #retunrs a list of the index of every symbol in list [1,2] in given example

    if direction == 'RIGHT':
        if ind[-1]+1 == len(lst):                       #check to see if the right most move will go out of the list 
            return False
        for x in ind[::-1]:
            lst.insert(x+1,lst.pop(x))                  #this will pop out every symbol and insert them back in one to the right  


    if direction == 'LEFT':
        if ind[0] == 0:                                 #checks if the left most symbol is at 0
            return False 
        for x in ind:
            lst.insert(x-1,lst.pop(x))                  #this will pop out every symbol and insert them back in one to the left

    return(True,lst)                                    #return the new list and a True in a tuplit
```

.

```
>>> a = [['.', 'B', 'B', '.', '.']]
>>> print(move_sideways('B', 'RIGHT', a[0]))
(True, ['.', '.', 'B', 'B', '.'])

>>> a = [['.', 'B', 'B', '.', 'B']]
>>> print(move_sideways('B', 'RIGHT', a[0]))
False
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. For some reason when I run it with the test cases it says IndexError: list index out of range not sure what is causing this

Comment: @n00bprogrammer22 are you doing a = [['.', 'B', 'B', '.', '.']] or a = ['.', 'B', 'B', '.', '.'] (note the double brackets [[]] )

Comment: It is double brackets as sometimes there is more then 1 list but I believe only 1 list is modified in each case

Comment: when you have double brakets it means you have a list of lists ex: a = [[list 1],[list 2]]. The function only accepts single lists so to just call one list use brackets after the name so a[0] will give you [list1] and a[1] will give you [list2].

Comment: @n00bprogrammer22 I added a check that will stop any IndexError. It will now return False if the symbol is not in the list.